# Need help parsing tags in an XML file and replacing them with a new value

Tags: python, python-2.7, xml-parsing

I'm trying to mod that phone number script from a few weeks back to help a friend out. This is the script I am using as a starting point.

```
# import regular expressions 
import re
# import argv 
from sys import argv

#arguments to provide at command line 
script, filename = argv

#load the file
data = open(filename)
#read the file
read_file = data.read()

# create a regular expression to filter out phone numbers 
phone_finder = re.compile(r"\(\d{3}\)\s*\d{3}-\d{4}")

# r to tell its a raw string
# \( to match "("
# \d{3} to match 3 digits
# \) to match ")"
# \s* account for no spaces
# \d{3} to match 3 digits
# - to match an "-"
# \d{4} to match 4 digits

# print the results
print phone_finder.findall(read_file)
```

he wants a way to search through an XML file and look for "`<excerpt:encoded><![CDATA[]]></excerpt:encoded>"`
 or

```
<excerpt:encoded><![CDATA[We love having a frother to make a latte or cappuccino, and think you'll enjoy some hot milk on these cold winter nights to put you to sleep as well.]]></excerpt:encoded>
```

and replace all instances with

```
<excerpt:encoded><![CDATA[]]></excerpt:encoded>
```

but I am not sure how thats going to work because in that second example the text will be different with each instance in the file.

I am new to Python so any help would be appreciated.
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

To remove all content from `<excerpt:encoded>` elements:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as etree

etree.register_namespace('excerpt', 'your namespace') # to preserve prefix

# read xml
doc = etree.parse(filename)

# clear elements
for element in doc.iter(tag='{your namespace}encoded'): 
    element.clear()

# write xml
doc.write(filename + '.cleared')
```

You should replace `'your namespace'` by the actual namespace `excerpt` prefix refers to.